# Проблема с Folium

Tags: python

Работаю с Anaconda, докачал folium через conda в терминале, но при запуске этого кода выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\folium.py", line 1, in <module>
    import folium
  File "d:\folium.py", line 3, in <module>
    cart = folium.Map(location=[37,296933, -121, 9574983], zoom_start=8)
AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'Map'
```

Вот код:

```
import folium
cart = folium.Map(location=[37,296933, -121, 9574983], zoom_start=8)
cart.save("cart.html")
```

Comment: Переименуйте файл.

Comment: Проблема не в этом - он подсвечивает мне folium во второй строке и пишет, что такого класса там нет. Его и правда нет, потому что там две папки с названием фолиум, модуль map во внутренней, но я не могу прописать путь к нему, потому что folium.folium.map выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Вы файл-то переименуйте.

Comment: Html? Я его переименовал в f.html. Пока что ничего не происходит. Вот что пишет: Module 'folium' has no 'Map' member. А вот код:import folium
import pandas as pd

cart = folium.Map(location=[37,296933, -121, 9574983], zoom_start=8)

cart.save("f.html")

Comment: Я ещё так сделал:

Comment: from folium import map
import pandas as pd

cart = map.Map(location=[37,296933, -121, 9574983], zoom_start=8)

cart.save("f.html")

Comment: Но он просто не видит файл, хотя я захожу и могу открыть его спокойно (я про файл map.py)

Comment: Нет, вы питон-файл переименуйте-то. Тот, который d:\folium.py